# MultiProcessing Signal handling: Why isn't parent task killed when child task is terminated?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

As per my understanding, when using "fork" context, a signal delivered to a subprocess triggers parent's handler.

https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/75670

However that doesn't seem to be the case for this example:

```
import time
import asyncio

from pebble import ProcessPool
import multiprocessing

SLEEP = 10
TIMEOUT = 2
import signal

def function(seconds):
    print(f"Going to sleep {seconds}s..")
    
    
    time.sleep(seconds)
    print(f"Slept {seconds}s.")


def stop(reaons:str="caught signals"):
    print("stopping")

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    pool = ProcessPool(2, context=multiprocessing.get_context("fork"))
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, stop)
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGTERM, stop)
 

    try:
        fut = pool.schedule(function, (SLEEP,), timeout=TIMEOUT)

        await asyncio.wrap_future(fut, loop=loop)
    except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError:
        print("caught exception")




if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

prints:

```
Going to sleep 10s..
caught exception
```

I would have expected it to trigger the signal handler on the parent task (`stop`) as well. Why didn't that happen?

Comment: Do note that you linked _to a bug_, not to documentation of a feature. Writing code that takes deliberate advantage of bugs tends to be poor form, because bugs tend to get fixed; certainly, to the extent that there are test cases around them, the tests are written to try to _reduce_ their repeatability rather to ensure that they reliably take place along all scenarios in which the language is supported. In particular, this bug was fixed in https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/99539

Answer (score 1):

This bug was fixed in [`python/cpython#99539` (aka GH-66285)](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/99539), merged in November of 2022; consequently, the behavior described no longer takes place.

Moreover, [`Lib/test/test_asyncio/test_unix_events.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/test/test_asyncio/test_unix_events.py) now contains a regression test to prevent this behavior from taking place in the future.

Comment: I'm running into an issue at work with the symptoms exactly as described in the bug. Do you know how i might be able to ascertain if this bug is the rootcause? Do I have to check library version? 

I tried `importlib.metadata.version("asyncio")` but that tells me "no package found". How can I confirm that the bug is rootcause?

Comment: I just found out that we're using 3.10.5 at work...I need to check what version the fix landed in

Comment: For what it's worth, I ran the code snippet on 3.9 but the fix only landed in 3.12...so my understanding is wrong.